# Excel VBA - Check if newer .xlsm exists

Tags: vba, excel

can you help me with this problem? I have .xlsm file which is distributed over company. Each company member have a one cope and have access to same folder on network drive (for example V:/Excel/Apps) I found a little function to check if file exists:

```
Function fileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim obj_fso As Object

    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)

End Function
```

but I'really don't know how to check if file with same name is newer or not.
I can use version directly in filename, but it doesn't solve my problem, because my e.g excelApp_0.1.xlsm is unable to know, if newer searched version will be v0.2 or 0.8 or 1.6. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `obj_fso.getFile(filespec)` to get the FILE object, then use `file.DateCreated`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to UncleO, it works :-)

```
Function newerFileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim obj_fso As Object

    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)
    If fileExists Then
        Dim file As Object
        Dim s As String
        Dim currentDate As Object
        Dim newerDate As String
        Set file = obj_fso.getFile(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)
        Set currentDate = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
        newerDate = file.DateCreated
        's = "Current file creation date: " & currentDate & vbCrLf
        's = s & "Newer file creation date: " & newerDate
        'MsgBox s
        If newerDate > currentDate Then
            newerFileExists = True
        Else
            newerFileExists = False
        End If
    Else
    newerFileExists = False
    End If
End Function
```