# Need to modify an existing code to STOP it from overwriting an existing file, if present

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify this code to first search if a file exists, if so, do nothing but show a message, if not, the code below will automatically create the file. Thanks in advance.

```
    Option Explicit
    Public WithEvents MonitorApp As Application

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim strGenericFilePath      As String: strGenericFilePath = "\\Server2016\Common\Register\"
    Dim strYear                 As String: strYear = Year(Date) & "\"
    Dim strMonth                As String: strMonth = MonthName(Month(Date)) & "\"
    Dim strFileName             As String: strFileName = "Register Sheet " & Format(Date, "mmm dd yyyy")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear
    End If

    If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth
    End If

    If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strFileName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "File Saved As: " & vbNewLine & strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strFileName

    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any "code below".

Comment: This is almost impossible to read.  Please edit your original post with the code and someone will format it for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53329272/edit

Comment: ok. I figured out how to post it correctly. Let me know if you can help me with the code.

Comment: This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974950/excel-vba-check-if-newer-xlsm-exists  You could leave out the part of checking if the file is newer.

Comment: I've edited the code just needs peer review. Please please please write code neater.  I highly suggest reading: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/21759/A-Guide-to-Writing-Understandable-and-Maintainable-VBA-Code.html

Comment: `If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strFileName)) > 0 Then` should tell you if the file already exists

Comment: Hello again. How do you stop it from overwriting an existing file when you run the code?